# How might I develop this into a hypothesis test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

So I'm trying to test if there is statistically significant difference between the frequency of play of different recreational soccer players based on their stated reasons for play.

So for example: 
The average amount of times someone plays soccer per week when they state that exercise is their reason for play - compared to the frequency of someone who might say the social aspect is their reason. How might I set up such a hypothesis test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are vague aspects to your question. Here are some suggestions,
considerations, and one possibly relevant statistical procedure.

You should begin by specifying the population of occasional
soccer players in which you are interested. Perhaps
undergraduates at a particular university or in a particular
region. What is your definition of 'recreational soccer player'? In a
diverse student population, are you going to set age limits?
Will you include women?

Sample a number people from this population. Use the answer
to the motivational question so sort them into groups E (exercise)
or S (social). Then determine the 'typical' number of times per
week each subject plays soccer. You need to be clear what you mean by 'typical'
and 'playing soccer'. (Is it better to ask for the typical
number of hours a week spent playing soccer?)

Do a two-sample t test ('Welch', 'non-pooled', or 'separate
variances') to see if the sample means for the two groups indicate that the
population means for E and S differ. (You will also need the
sample standard deviations of the two groups.)

Consult a basic statistics
text for the formula of the test statistic and how to decide
whether to reject the hypothesis that groups E and S have
equal population means. Most statistical software packages
will perform such a test.

You should look at the data to see whether the numerical values
within E and S are consistent with normal. (If not, other kinds
of 2-sample tests are available.)

In the end, if you do not find
a statistically significant difference, you might do a power
computation to find out whether you have enough subjects in each group to
have a reasonable chance of detecting a difference of a particular
size. (Ideally, this sample-size determination would be done in advance of
your 'study', but you probably wouldn't know enough without a
pilot run to answer the necessary questions.)